# Need to create a custom box shadow effect

Tags: html, css

I have two divs for which I just need to add a box-shadow effect using CSS. But I just don't want it to get applied on every side of the div, I don't want the effect on the bottom side of the div. But I can't find a way to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried using the box shadow inspector that is available in Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: You would need to provide an image of what you are trying to recreate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use CSS property `box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px #888888;`

detail of the property `box-shadow:x-offset y-offset blur color`

```css
#example {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px #888888;
}
```

```html
<h2>box-shadow</h2>
<div id="example">
  <p>blurred</p>
</div>
```